# Windows store share link - not work

Tags: windows-store-apps

I submit app to Windows Store with "Hide this app in the Store. Customers with a direct link to the app’s listing can still download it"

App now is "In the Store"

But links from "App identity - You can share this link to help customers find your app in the Store:" not work - "We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found."

Why not work?

There are another way for hide app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the time since you published your application ? Usually, It takes around 2 ~ 4 hours to be available ..